# Java Sort List with custom Comparator

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I have my class :

```
public class Vehicle implements Comparable<Vehicle> {

....

 @Override
    public int compareTo(Vehicle o) {

       if (o.dataMatricula.compareTo(dataMatricula) ==0){
            return matricula.compareTo(o.matricula);   

        }
        else {
            return o.dataMatricula.compareTo(dataMatricula);
        }

...

}
```

And i'm trying to sort an array of Vehicle with a custom comparator from the class:

```
class CompararVehicle implements Comparator<Vehicle> {

    @Override
    public int compare(Vehicle o1, Vehicle o2) {
        if (o1 == o2) {
            return 0;
        }

        if(o2.getDataMatricula().compareTo(o1.getDataMatricula())==0){
            if(o1.getMatricula().compareTo(o2.getMatricula())==0){
                return 0;
            }
            else {
                   return o1.getMatricula().compareTo(o2.getMatricula());
            }
        }


        else {
            return o2.getDataMatricula().compareTo(o1.getDataMatricula());
        }

    }
}
```

But i get an error when I try to do this :

```
Arrays.sort(MyListofVehicle, new CompararVehicle());
```

Edit: MyListOfVehicle is a variable `List<Vehicle>`
The error i get from NetBeans is :

> error: no suitable method found for
>   sort(List,CompararVehicle)
>            Arrays.sort(llVeh, new CompararVehicle());
>       method Arrays.sort(T#1[],Comparator) is not applicable
>         (cannot infer type-variable(s) T#1

It's the fact that i already have a compareTo in my class "vehicle" interfering when I try to order the array with another standard? If so, how can i order by the new standard?

Comment: `Arrays.sort` can only sort an array, not a `List`. Perhaps you meant to use `Collections.sort`.

Comment: Is `MyListofVehicle` a type? It's spelled like one, not like a variable. If it is a (misspelled) variable, what is its type? The error says something about a `List`, but you're asking for a sort of an array. You can't sort something that is not an array using a method to sort an array.

Comment: It's a List of Vehicle ,Edited!

Answer (score 0):

Your **MyListofVehicle** is a **List** (List) not an **array** 
so uyou cant use Arrays.sort method 
try this

```
Collections.sort(MyListofVehicle, new CompararVehicle());
```

or you can do something like this

```
Arrays.sort(MyListofVehicle.toArray(new Vehicle[0]), new CompararVehicle());
```